# What is a good way to get the dynamic title of a page in Django?

Tags: python, html, django, twitter, social-networking

I'm trying to customize a share on Twitter button and I'm using to this to share:

http://twitter.com/intent/tweet?status=[TITLE]+[URL]

I'm able to get the URL with {{ request.get_host }} and {{ request.path }}, but I can't seem to get the title working. Are there any request objects I can use to get the title of my current page title? Thanks.

Comment: show your view code for this page.  I assume you create title in view, and pass it to your template.  Use that template variable

Comment: I'm using standard block titles. {% block title %}title{% endblock %}Try to insert it here doesn't seem to work: http://twitter.com/intent/tweet?status={% block title %}{% endblock %}+[URL]. Please excuse my ignorance in this. I just started learning Python & Django.

Comment: set title in your context that is passed to template.  In template us `{{ title }}`.  Show your view code in your question

Comment: I haven't written any code to handle the title in my view so I can't really show anything. I guess that's the next step...write some code to handle the title. I thought there was an easier way since I can get the URL without additional code.

Comment: The url is available because of how http works.  But your title is up to you.

Answer (score 9):

The easiest way to do this is:
Insert the following code in your base.html

```
#base.html
{% block title %} {% endblock %}
```

and following in your index or any Html file with your title

```
#index.html
{% extends 'base.html'%}
{% block title %} My Page Title {% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Place your context object key in double paranthesis.
Lets take am making a dynamic teacher's page in a school management system

```
#urls.py
path("teacher/<str:pk>/",views.teacher,name="teacher"),
```

The vew

```
#view
def teacher(request,pk):
    teacher = Teacher.objects.get(id=pk)
    context= {"teacher":teacher}
    return render(request,'main/teacher.html',context)
```

The template

```
 <title>{{teacher.fname}} Page</title>
```